# Inequality with absolute value of sum of terms

Tags: inequality

I am having the following inequality 
$$x>|A+B+C+D|$$
and I can prove that $|A|<a$, $|B|<b$, $|C|<c$ and $|D|<d$

Can I express the inequality in terms of $a,b,c,d$? Or am I following the wrong road here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have the wrong inequality $x>$...

Imagine you have four points A,B,C,D on the positive line close to each other, and four point a,b,c,d very far away to the right (bigger) and you say that $x$ is bigger than $A+B+C+D$ (if a,b,c,d are very far away then A+B+C+D is still far away from a,b,c and d). This does not seem to say much about a,b,c,d. The value x can still be less than all of them, or stuck in between a,b,c or d or even further right. Don't you think? I guess you need more information.